# Prove that $\frac{a}{2}x^2+bx+c=0$ has a root between $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Tags: quadratics, functional-equations

If $x_1$ and $x_2$ are non-zero roots of the equations $ax^2+bx+c=0$ and $-ax^2+bx+c=0$

respectively. Prove that $\frac{a}{2}x^2+bx+c=0$ has a root between $x_1$ and $x_2$.

> Please help me ..

Comment: Over what? $ \Bbb R$?

Comment: $x_1$and $x_2$ are non zero roots.

Comment: Have you used the fact that $bx+c=0 $ so that $x=-c/b$

Comment: $ac^2/2b^2=0$ so then, $ac^2=0$ which implies that $a=0 or c=0$

Comment: I try $f(x_1)=\frac{a}{2}x_1^2+bx_1+c$ and $f(x_2)=\frac{a}{2}x_2^2+bx_2+c$

Comment: I'm just checking that you used that it maybe helpful

Comment: Yes, then these are roots so that $0=\frac{a}{2}x_2^2+bx_2+c$ and that $0=\frac{a}{2}x_1^2+bx_1+c$

Comment: Assume that it does not have a real root between $x_1 $ and $x_2$. Then...?

Comment: Thanks for helping me. now I am able to solve this question

Comment: This is a good question. +1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $f(x)=\frac{a}{2}x^2+bx+c$, then $f(x_1)=-\frac{a}{2}x_1^2$ and $f(x_2)=\frac{3a}{2}x_2^2$. Consequently  $f(x_1)f(x_2)<0$. By continuity it should have a root in $(x_1,x_2)$.

Comment: $f(x_1)f(x_2) = 3a^2x_1^2x_2^2/4 > 0$.

Comment: @martycohen there was a typo (cut paste error). I have fixed it.